# Attempting to extend FormControlDirective to implement my own FormControl directive results in faulty binding

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-di

I'm trying to inverse the way forms controls are registering themselves onto a `FormGroup`, so that instead of having to

```
@Component({..., template: `<input [formControl]="myControl"`}    
...
```

Or

```
@Component({..., template: `<input [formControName]="myControlName"`}    
...
```

I could

```
@Component({..., template: `<input myFormControl`}    
...
```

And have my directive create and add the `FormControl` for me.

**It is best explained with this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9IHXCKzVqLJTDM4A2iWc?p=info).**

What doesn't seem to work is the binding the view to the form model, as you can see, changing the the input does not change the form model value.

*Debugging it shows that there are no `valueAccessor` injected to the constructor (unlike when using the base `FormControlDirective` class directly).*

If you're wondering, my end goal would be that I would have a parent customized group component that would `@ViewChildren(MyFormDirective)`, and dynamically add them all to it's created form.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Please see my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439836/extending-formcontroldirective-in-angular-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. There is one more trick though. There isn't `DefaultValueAccessor` for that input element, thus constructor arguments are populate with `null` value.

The `formControl` \ `formControlName` selectors appear in one more place - [the value accessor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts#L47). In order your directive to work you should implement all default value accessors for the `hybridFormControl` directive ( following the pattern for the built-in directives).

P.S I believe the provider of your directive should be corrected to

```
providers: [{
    provide: NgControl, //<-- NgControl is the key
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => HybridFormControlDirective)
}]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by "implement all default value accessors". Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: My so question on the matter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439836/extending-formcontroldirective-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Odd that there aren't more Stackoverflow posts about this. The above answer did not work for me, but this is how I solved it in the case that there are more out there.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[hybridFormControl]'
})
class HybridFormControl Directive extends FormControlName implements ControlValueAccessor, OnChanges {
  @Input('hybridFormControl') name: string;

  onChange;
  onTouched;

  constructor(
      @Optional() protected formGroupDirective: FormGroupDirective,
      @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR) valueAccessors: ControlValueAccessor[],
      private fb: FormBuilder,
      private renderer: Renderer2,
      private element: ElementRef
  ) {
    super(formGroupDirective, [], [], valueAccessors, null);
    this.valueAccessor = this;
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (!this._registered) {
      // dynamically create the form control model on the form group model.
      this.formGroup = this.formGroupDirective.form;
      this.formGroup.registerControl(name, this.fb.control(''));
      this._registered = true;
    }

    // IMPORTANT - this ties your extended form control to the form control 
    // model on the form group model that we just created above. Take a look
    // at Angular github source code.
    super.ngOnChanges(changes); 
  }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value'])
  @HostListener('change', ['$event.target.value'])
  onInput(value): void {
    this.onChange(modelValue);
  }

  writeValue(value): void {
    const element = this.element.nativeElement;
    this.renderer.setProperty(element, 'value', value);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

And this hybrid component could be used like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <form formGroup=[formGroup]>
      <input type="text" hybridFormControl="myName">
    </form>
  `
class AppComponent {
  formGroup: FormGroup

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({});
  }
}
```

Sources: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts#L212