# Custom ControlValueAccessor doesn't seem to work for my own FormControl directive

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I am trying to implement this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44828452/7295576) as I have been attempting to create my own custom `FormControl` as detailed in that question as well.

I have created a custom `ControlValueAccessor` and this gets injected as the `valueAccessor` into the constructor of my `FormControl` Directive, but when I try registering a callback with the `registerOnChange` function it never gets called.

In fact none of the members seem to get called.

I have read through lots of articles and blog posts but can't work out what I am missing or doing wrong.

I have extended the plunkr from the original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44812220/attempting-to-extend-formcontroldirective-to-implement-my-own-formcontrol-direct) to demonstrate [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/IvdS0RiKoTDklAtBqguy).

Any help, or pointers, would be greatly appreciated.

*The goal is like the other question to be able to do `@Component({..., template: '<input myFormControl...'}...` to register FormControls.*

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Check out this post on how to ask questions that are likely to be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  In your case you might show something more about what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:). There is one more trick though.

Your custom `NgControl` doesn't call `setUpControl` function that [is called](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_directive.ts#L88-L90) inside `ngOnChanges` of `FormControlDirective`. That's because `@Inputs` of your custom control are not changed. Moreover you don't use any inputs on your control.

But you can run it manually:

```typescript
import { SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';

export class HybridFormControlDirective extends FormControlDirective   {
  /* @override */
  constructor(...) {
      super(validators, asyncValidators, valueAccessors);
      this.form = new FormControl('');
      this.form.patchValue('test2');

      // manually call ngOnChanges to make sure that setUpControl is called
      this.ngOnChanges({
        form: new SimpleChange(undefined, this.form, true)
      });
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/2CEZfjpovqk0iLDpyAkC?p=preview)**